# Django Cached Class

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a class in my Django project that corresponds to a DB table that I don't expect to change. There are 4 rows in this table and I would like to cache them when the application first opens and then just hit the cache from then on.

Is my best bet using the [Low Level Cache API](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter15.html)? If so, how can I then call that from every other view in my application? I just access the same cache variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are constant, why not hard code them?
Anyway, you can cache them in global variables (for example, in some module), that way you will have to pay for accessing them (network-wise) only once per app instance.

e.g. something like:

```
# module global_vals
VAL1 = get_from_db("...")
VAL2 = get_from_db("...")
```

then access them

```
import global_vals
def foo():
  v1 = global_vals.VAL1
  v2 = global_vals.VAL2
```

Comment: They may change every month or so and I wanted to just do a DB update instead of having to change the code to get the new values. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In this case, you need to reload the code, but you don't have to change it, so I'm not sure my suggestion is the best.